# Keep projectile and treemacs in sync

Tags: projectile, treemacs

Since projectile and treemacs are independent project and treemacs-projectile is written as helper. However I fail to understand the concept of it.

I want to see all my projectile projects be shows in treemacs as I add them via projectile (and be added to projectile if I add them to treemacs). And if I close a project in either mode it should be closed with all its buffers.

Right now I achieve the same result by calling commands from each manually. Which is very cumbersome.

How can I keep treemacs and projectile in sync?